# Pymongo .find() query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently learning coding & am extremely new to it
In my program i am running this command

What i am trying to do is use two attributes to find a record. If the two attributes are correct it will allow the user to continue using the program.

What is happening is that querying this it only cares about the first input (name) and whether or not the second input is correct will continue as it finds the correct name.

I want my program to query using mongodb which user has the name eg.. "Admin" and job title "Store manager" i have this setup in the db already. So for example if they were to type name as "Admin" and title as "till op" it would then trigger the "User not found". Any help is welcomed.

```
name = input("Please enter your name ")

job = input("Please enter your ID ")

myquery = name

myquery2 = job

myquery3 = (myquery, myquery2)

print(myquery3)

docu = staff_collection.collection.find_one({"Full Name": myquery}, {"Job_Role": myquery2})


if docu is not None:

    print(docu)

else:
    print("User not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your .find query parameter is wrong. Instead of :

```
docu = staff_collection.collection.find_one({"Full Name": myquery}, {"Job_Role": myquery2})
```

It should be :

```
docu = staff_collection.collection.find_one({"Full Name": myquery, "Job_Role": myquery2})
```

I didn't fully understand your question. This approach is making sure that "Full Name" is the same as myquery and "Job Role" is the same as myquery2 in mongo and if so, returns a document.

If you are interested in using **$or** operator please refer to it [here](https://www.mongodbtutorial.org/mongodb-crud/mongodb-or/).

It's not the official docs, but I think this one is explained better

Cheers

Comment: That worked exactly how i wanted. Thank you
Yeah i explained it pretty badly sorry for making it so difficult.
I basically wanted it to search for both attribute Name and Job Role & if the user types in the name and job role correctly it should find the ID from the DB. If not it should then just display an error message & re-start program.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the second filter as one of the optional `*args` of `find_one()`

(most likely `projection`, since `find_one`'s `*args` and `kwargs` are just collections of the more generic `find`'s signature).

You just need to put both queries in the same dict passed as `filter` argument. Also there are a lot of (*appearently*) redundant reference variables

```
name = input("Please enter your name ")
job = input("Please enter your ID ")
print(job, name)

print(staff_collection.collection.find_one({"Full Name": myquery, "Job_Role": myquery2}) or "User not found")
```